# Yii2 in Third Party systems for ActiveRecord. How to deal with exceptions

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, exception, yii2

I use Yii2 with my framework because I like ActiveRecord and QueryBuilder.
[Yii2 Official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-yii-in-others)
describes how to use it.

It works, but Yii2 takes all control of PHP exceptions and warnings in `ErrorHandler.php`

```php
/**
 * Register this error handler
 */
public function register()
{
    ini_set('display_errors', false);
    set_exception_handler([$this, 'handleException']);
    if (defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
        set_error_handler([$this, 'handleHhvmError']);
    } else {
        set_error_handler([$this, 'handleError']);
    }
    if ($this->memoryReserveSize > 0) {
        $this->_memoryReserve = str_repeat('x', $this->memoryReserveSize);
    }
    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'handleFatalError']);
}
```

I don't know how to deal with it.

For example, I have DBException form Yii. If I set my own `set_exception_handler`, it will have very poor information about exception: only code and message. It will be very difficult to debug it without prepared query, query parameters, etc.

If I use Yii2's exception handler - I have to rewrite all my framework with Yii2 exceptions. Thats not good and I don't really like Yii2 letters and exception templates. All I need from Yii2 is work with DB.

Do you have any ideas how can I solve this situation?

Comment: I think you misinterpret the way it works. Yii exceptions don't hold more information than default PHP exceptions and Yii error handler handles every exception so you don't have to rewrite your code. SQL query in Yii 2 is logged by profiler.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to acheive here. Do you want to retain default php error handler or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, that Yii's Database Exception has all information about request and error. Also that Exception has some additional methods for another info. Thats enough to controll all Exceptions and errors by my Framework as usual.

So I rewrited all handlers again to my handlers

```
spl_autoload_register(array("MyClass", 'autoload'));
set_exception_handler(['MyClass','exceptionHandler']);
set_error_handler(['MyClass','errorHandler']);
```

and collect all usefull information to error `body`

```php
$body .= "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
$body .= "File: " . $e->getFile() . ":" . $e->getLine() . PHP_EOL;
$body .= "Trace:" .$e->getTraceAsString() . PHP_EOL;
$prev = $e->getPrevious();
if ($prev) {
    $body .= "Next To: ";
    $body .= get_class($prev)." ".PHP_EOL;
    $body .= $prev->getMessage();
}
if ($e instanceof yii\db\Exception) {
    $body .= "Additional Info: " . (print_r($e->errorInfo, true));
}
```